# Showing Live Camera Stream inside Xamarin.Forms App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms App in which I need to display the current camera stream in order to shoot a photo from inside the app. Has anyone an advice on how to implement that? Is that easily possible?

Thanks!

Edit:
I found an awesome sample project from Xamarin doing exactly what I need :)
https://xamarin.com/prebuilt/moments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much integration you need. You can start with something simple like: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Media

If that doesn't do what you need, you will need to create a custom renderer on each platform. It isn't too difficult but its more work.

Comment: ok, going with a custom renderer now :) I found a great point to start here: https://xamarin.com/prebuilt/moments